# I'm struggling to flatten two arrays within an object

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've got the following Object and I'm struggling to flatten the two arrays so they are one array.

Here is the object

```
{ 
  "id":"575802",
  "listOfStuff":[  
      "AB",
   ],
   "listOfDocs":[  
      [  
         {  
            "doc_id":"123456",
            "id":"123",
            "filename":"myFileName.pdf",
         }
      ],
      [  
         {  
            "doc_id":"1234",
            "id":"123",
            "filename":"myFileName2.pdf",
         }
      ]
   ]
}
```

This is the output I'm aiming for:

```
{  
   "id":"575802",
   "listOfStuff":[  
      "AB",
   ],
   "listOfDocs":[ 
         {  
            "doc_id":"123456",
            "id":"123",
            "filename":"myFileName.pdf",
         } ,
         {  
            "doc_id":1234,
            "id":"123",
            "filename":"myFileName2.pdf",
         }
   ]
}
```

I've tried to do the following to flatten the array but that hasn't worked.

```
Array.prototype.concat.apply([], row.listOfDocs);
```

Comment: You have word processor quotes in your source code. Please replace them with regular quotes and don't use word processors to write code.

Comment: `obj.listOfDocs = obj.listOfDocs.map(arr => arr[0]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const data =  {
  "id": "575802",
  "listOfStuff": [
    "AB"
  ],
  "listOfDocs": [[
    {
      "doc_id": "123456",
      "id": "123",
      "filename": "myFileName.pdf"
    }],
    [{
      "doc_id": 1234,
      "id": "123",
      "filename": "myFileName2.pdf"
    }
  ]]
}

data.listOfDocs = data.listOfDocs.reduce((acc, val) => acc.concat(val), [])

console.log(data);
```

You can use `.flat()`, you will also need a polyfill for that for IE.

Instead of using flat you can resolve your problem using the above solution.

Answer (score 0):

use  [flat function](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Objets_globaux/Array/flat),try this:

```js
const data  =  {
  "id": "575802",
  "listOfStuff": [
    "AB"
  ],
  "listOfDocs": [
    {
      "doc_id": "123456",
      "id": "123",
      "filename": "myFileName.pdf"
    },
    {
      "doc_id": 1234,
      "id": "123",
      "filename": "myFileName2.pdf"
    }
  ]
}

const result = {...data, listOfDocs:data.listOfDocs.flat()};

console.log(result);
```